# R non-linear model

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

[image]

I have the above plot of y vs x1. in this analysis, I have a few more predictors namely x2, x3 and x4. I'm more concerned with y vs x1 but keeping in mind as well x2, x3 and x4 all affect y. I'm relatively new to R and i'm not sure how to fit it to a non-linear model in R. Also, even ignoring x2 to x4, I'm not sure what is a good fit. I'm hoping to find a good non linear model fit and subsequently plot the non linear curve on to this plot.

Comment: Since you're so new to what you're doing, I would recommend starting with the basics. [This is a good tutorial for regular linear regression with R](http://r-statistics.co/Linear-Regression.html). There are links on the side to more advance regression techniques - but if you don't even know how to model Y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 (multiple linear regression) yet then I wouldn't jump right into non-linear regression. You may very well not even need it

Comment: This really isn't a question about programming; it seems to be a question about model fitting. Such questions belong on [stats.se] or [datascience.se], not Stack Overflow. You need to know exactly what model you want to fit to your data before you ask how to do it in R. And even the, when asking on this site, you should include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data and describe where exactly you are getting stuck.